# UPDATE statement format analogous to INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I know that the `UPDATE` statement has the following format:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

I was wondering whether there exists a format analogous to `INSERT` statement, something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Is this a valid query?

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - no.

All the variants of the `update` syntax have a `set` clause of the form `colulmn1=..., column2=...` etc. For a complete list of the supported syntax variants, you can [check out the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Comment: Isn't that a bit strange? I got used to generating columns fields and values for `INSERT` statement using the `implode` method which seems pretty handy. Any particular reason why this isn't supported?